# Python: creating output that shows the shift in identical row entries between two columns

Tags: python, row, shift

The goal is to see differences between two columns which each contain the identical row entries, just on different lines;

```
[
["ENSCAFG00000008901","ENSCAFG00000013762"],
["ENSCAFG00000029470","ENSCAFG00000003029"],
["ENSCAFG00000013782","ENSCAFG00000007249"],
["ENSCAFG00000000806","ENSCAFG00000012468"],
["ENSCAFG00000013341","ENSCAFG00000018167"],
["ENSCAFG00000003376","ENSCAFG00000003376"],
["ENSCAFG00000000812","ENSCAFG00000018164"],
["ENSCAFG00000012468","ENSCAFG00000001591"],
["ENSCAFG00000031786","ENSCAFG00000013782"],
["ENSCAFG00000000803","ENSCAFG00000030793"],
["ENSCAFG00000003029","ENSCAFG00000015177"],
["ENSCAFG00000011565","ENSCAFG00000005750"]
]
```

This list had many more rows, so I can't do it by hand. For example, we see ENSCAFG00000003029 on the 11th row in the first column and on the 2th row in the second column. I'd like to create some output that shows the shift in rows between the first and second column in relation to the first column. So in the case of ENSCAFG00000003029, we I would like to see +9 (or something like that) after the row where ENSCAFG00000003029 appears in the first column.

I hope my goal is clear and this is the right place to ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to be efficient for very long lists, but this should work:

```
lst = [
    ["ENSCAFG00000008901","ENSCAFG00000013762"],
    ["ENSCAFG00000029470","ENSCAFG00000003029"],
    ["ENSCAFG00000013782","ENSCAFG00000007249"],
    ["ENSCAFG00000000806","ENSCAFG00000012468"],
    ["ENSCAFG00000013341","ENSCAFG00000018167"],
    ["ENSCAFG00000003376","ENSCAFG00000003376"],
    ["ENSCAFG00000000812","ENSCAFG00000018164"],
    ["ENSCAFG00000012468","ENSCAFG00000001591"],
    ["ENSCAFG00000031786","ENSCAFG00000013782"],
    ["ENSCAFG00000000803","ENSCAFG00000030793"],
    ["ENSCAFG00000003029","ENSCAFG00000015177"],
    ["ENSCAFG00000011565","ENSCAFG00000005750"]
    ]

col_1 = [x[0] for x in lst]
col_2 = [x[1] for x in lst]

idx_offset = [None] * len(col_1)
for col_1_idx, val_1 in enumerate(col_1):
    try:
        col_2_idx = col_2.index(val_1)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    idx_offset[col_1_idx] = col_2_idx - col_1_idx
```

In short, for each value in the first column, find the index of that same value in the second column (if it exists). Take this index, and deduct from it the index of the value in the first column, and that's your output. The output (`idx_offset`) will be `None` for elements in the first column that don't occur in the second column. In this case, the output would become:

```
[None, None, 6, None, None, 0, None, -4, None, None, -9, None]
```

Comment: This is the output i'd like, however, when I input this I do not get the output (or any) you describe in your post. Moreover, is there an easy way to append the output to the lines they belong to?

Comment: The above indeed doesn't produce output. You can easily make a new copy of your original list with the index offset appended though: `outp = [[val_1, val_2, idx] for (val_1, val_2, idx) in zip(col_1, col_2, idx_offset)]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to loop through twice. For example, if you make the simplifying assumption that the entries in the first column are unique, you could do:

```
cols = [['ENSCAFG00000008901', 'ENSCAFG00000013762'],
        ['ENSCAFG00000029470', 'ENSCAFG00000003029'],
        ['ENSCAFG00000013782', 'ENSCAFG00000007249'],
        ['ENSCAFG00000000806', 'ENSCAFG00000012468'],
        ['ENSCAFG00000013341', 'ENSCAFG00000018167'],
        ['ENSCAFG00000003376', 'ENSCAFG00000003376'],
        ['ENSCAFG00000000812', 'ENSCAFG00000018164'],
        ['ENSCAFG00000012468', 'ENSCAFG00000001591'],
        ['ENSCAFG00000031786', 'ENSCAFG00000013782'],
        ['ENSCAFG00000000803', 'ENSCAFG00000030793'],
        ['ENSCAFG00000003029', 'ENSCAFG00000015177'],
        ['ENSCAFG00000011565', 'ENSCAFG00000005750']]
positions = dict((x[0], i) for i, x in enumerate(cols))
[positions[x[1]]-i for i, x in enumerate(cols) if x[1] in positions]
```

Output:

```
[9, 4, 0, -6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 =[]
l2 =[]
for item in cols:
    l1.append(item[0])
    l2.append(item[0])
for item in l1:
    if item in l2:
        print str(l2.index(item)) + ':'  + str(item)
```